# docker-compose run with specified network name

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with three services (Solr, PostgreSQL and pgAdmin), all sharing a Docker network.

```
version: '2'
services:
  solr:
    image: solr:7.7.2
    ports:
      - '8983:8983'
    networks:
      primus-dev:
        ipv4_address: 10.105.1.101
    volumes:
      - data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - primus
      - /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs
    environment:
      - SOLR_HEAP=2048m
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 5m

  db:
    image: "postgres:11.5"
    container_name: "primus_postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      primus-dev:
        ipv4_address: 10.105.1.102
    volumes:
      - primus_dbdata:/var/lib/postgres/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=primus75
      - POSTGRES_USER=primus
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=primstav

  pgadm4:
    image: "dpage/pgadmin4"
    networks:
      primus-dev:
        ipv4_address: 10.105.1.103
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
    volumes:
      - /home/nils/docker-home:/var/docker-home
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=nils.weinander@kulturit.se
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=dev

networks:
  primus-dev:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.105.1.0/24

volumes:
  data:
  primus_dbdata:
```

This works just fine after **docker-compose up** (at least pgAdmin can talk to PostgreSQL).

But, then I have a script (actuall a make target, but that's not the point here), which builds, runs and deletes a container with **docker-compose run**:

```
docker-compose run -e HOME=/app -e PYTHONPATH=/app/server -u 0 --rm backend \
    bash -c 'cd /app/server && python tools/reindex_mp.py -s -n'
```

This does not work as the reindex_mp.py cannot reach Solr on 10.105.1.101, as the one shot container is not on the same Docker network. So, is there a way to tell docker-compose to use a named network with **docker-compose run**? **docker run** has an option **--network** but that is not available for docker-compose.

Comment: Can't you edit the docker-compose file of `backend` service and make it use `primus-dev` network?

Comment: **backend** is defined in another docker-compose file, but it works if I duplicate the network definition in that. There are other issues to work out, but it seems like this is possible.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a docker network outside your docker-compose and use that network while running services in docker-compose.

```
docker network create my-custom-created-network
```

now inside your docker-compose, use this network like this:

```
services:
  serv1:
    image: img
    networks:
      - my-custom-created-network

networks:
  my-custom-created-network:
    external: true
```

The network creation example creates a bridge network.
To access containers across hosts, use an overlay network.

You can also use the network created inside docker-compose and connect containers to that network.

Docker creates a default network for docker-compose and services which do not have any network configuration specified, will be using default network created by docker for that compose file.

you can find the network name by executing this command:

```
docker network ls
```

Use the network appropriate name while starting a container, like this

```
docker run [options] --network <network-name> <image-name>
```

Note: Containers in a same network are accessible using container names, you can leverage this instead of using ips

Comment: Thanks! This sounds good. I ran into other issues and abandoned the setup for the moment, but will keep this is mind for future use.

Answer (score 1):

I got the below error attempting Suhas answer.

**"services.netbox.networks must be a list"**

Adding a dash fixed it for me, e.g.

```
services:
  serv1:
    image: img
    networks:
    - my-custom-created-network

networks:
  my-custom-created-network:
    external: true
```